# Get the names of $_POST variables by value

Tags: php, arrays, post

If I have several post results that are like this:

```
$_POST["ResponseA"] = 1, $_POST["ResponseB"] = 1, $_POST["ResponseC"] = 2, $_POST["ResponseD"] = 3, $_POST["ResponseE"] = 1, etc.
```

How can I perform a loop that gets an array based upon the values? So If I'm checking for a value of 1, I get ResponseA, ResponseB, ResponseE ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $results = array_keys($_POST, 1);
    var_dump($results);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_flip()` like this...

```
$flipped = array_flip($_POST);

echo $flipped['1']; // ResponseA
```

You will get issues doing this though as your values are not unique

Answer (score 0):

simple build a loop

```
  <?php
     $fields = array('ResponseA','ResponseB','ResponseC','ResponseD','ResponseE')

     function searchValue(array $fields, $value) {
         $out = array();
         foreach($fields as $name) {
           if(isset($_POST[$name]) && $_POST[$name] == $value) $out[]=$name;
         }
         return $out;
      }
      var_dump(searchValue($fields,1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the $_POST:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if ($value == 1) {
    // $key will equal the value ResponseA if $_POST["ResponseA"] = 1
  }
}
```